# import lottie to gradle

Tags: android, kotlin, gradle

I want to add lottie dependency in my project.
this is the way that lottie document recommends

```
implementation "com.airbnb.android:lottie-compose:$lottieVersion"

allprojects {
repositories {
    ...
    maven { url "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/" }
}}
```

here is my gradle

```
buildscript {
ext {
    compose_version = '1.1.1'
    lottie_version = '0.5.4-SNAPSHOT'
}}
plugins {
id 'com.android.application' version '7.1.1' apply false
id 'com.android.library' version '7.1.1' apply false
id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android' version '1.6.10' apply false}
task clean(type: Delete) {
delete rootProject.buildDir}
```

as you can see there is no `allProjects` in my gradle.

how can I add Maven repository?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to your **build.gradle module** and inside **dependencies** section add

`implementation "com.airbnb.android:lottie-compose:$lottieVersion"`

Now go in **settings.gradle** and inside **dependencyResolutionManagement** -> **repositories** add  this

`maven { url "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/" }`